# Can't autoload a helper file - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I have a helper file located at

```
app/Helpers/Navigation.php
```

Helper file with namespace:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Navigation
{
    public static function isActiveRoute($route, $output = 'active')
    {
        if (Route::currentRouteName() == $route) {
            return $output;
        }
    }
}
```

i wanted to autoload this file . So in my composer.json i have this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/Helpers/Navigation.php"
    ]
  },
```

In my view i want to do this:

```
<li class="{{ isActiveRoute('main') }}">
```

But i get the error:

```
Call to undefined function isActiveRoute()
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong. I  did composer dumpautoload when i changed the composer file. I tried installing composer again, that also didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `helpers` file you don't want to be using a class. You would jut define the functions you want to use.

Also, it is good practice to wrap your function in a check to make sure that function doesn't already exist.

Replace the content of you `Naviation.php` with:

```
<?php

if (! function_exists('isActiveRoute')) {

    /**
     * [Description of this function]
     * 
     * @param $route
     * @param string $output
     * @return string
     */
    function isActiveRoute($route, $output = 'active')
    {
        if (Route::currentRouteName() == $route) {
            return $output;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: that seems like a good tip , but it doens't solve my autoload issue. I replaced my code, and i still get the same error

Comment: Not that you should need to but have you run `composer dumpautoload` again? Also, double check that your path in your composer file is correct i.e. case and spelling. Lastly, check that there isn't any sort of caching e.g. opcache.

Comment: yeah i was sure it must have been a spelling issue, but i triple checked everything and that does not seem the case. I might just go the service-provider route to make it work. Although that is just avoiding the problem.

Comment: Ok, so it worked when i did your solution and removed the namespace, because obviously the Route:: is in another namespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

i had the same issue, i'm assuming that you are using inspinia laravel version, so the problem is that they forgot to remove the file app/Helpers/Navigation.php

if you look the AppServiceProvider they are using the one in
'/../Http/Helpers/Helpers.php'

if you want to do Navigation::isActiveRoute then use the class file

but if you want to use `{{ isActiveRoute('youRouteName') }}` then you need to use the functions in '/../Http/Helpers/Helpers.php' and there is no need to use de composer.json (that was propossed in another solution for another problem)

i know i have the same feeling...

ps: Please sorry about my english

Answer (score 1):

When your helper file is a class then there is no need to autoload it.

Just create an alias in `config/app.php` as:

```
'aliases' => [
 ...
    'NavigationHelper' => App\Helpers\Navigation::class,
 ...
```

Use it in your Blade template as:

```
<li class="{{ NavigationHelper::isActiveRoute('main') }}">
```

At last, you can remove the following code from `composer.json` file and the  run `composer dumpautoload`

```
"files": [
  "app/Helpers/Navigation.php"
]
```

Comment: this works, but i feel like it's avoiding the problem a little bit. But this solves my error so its a valid solution! thanks

Comment: The solution of @Ross Wilson was more what i was looking for. but you get an upvote !